# Replace coefficients in a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

I want to replace the coefficients of a polynomial by new coefficients.

For example, my polynomial of variable 'r' is in the picture

[image: Input]

I want to replace the coefficients with 'a subscripts' similar to

> r^2 Subscript[a, 2] + r^4 Subscript[a, 4]

[image: Output]

Can this be done without having to manually replace everything?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps `Coefficient[ ...,r^2]` helps!

Comment: If you want the nice formatting of `Subscript`, mess as much as you like using `Format`, like in `Format[a[n_]]=Subscript[Style[a,Red],Style[n,Blue]]`, or use `Indexed` for symbolic vectors.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer, you should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://wolfr.am/vxtW3QtE) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [`DownValues`](https://wolfr.am/vxtQt6LX) to the operator `Subscript` and not an `OwnValues` to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://wolfr.am/vxtT6JDX)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to replace the long coefficients in front of r^2 and r^4 by letters a2 and a4, right? If yes, try the following. I will not repeat your lengthy expression, but instead write a short one:

```
expr = (A2 + B2)*r^2 + (A3 + B3)*r^4 + (A6 + B6)*r^6;
```

Now let us replace:

```
expr /. x_*r^n_Integer /; n == 2 || n == 4 :> Subscript[a, n]*r^n

(*   (A6 + B6) r^6 + r^2 Subscript[a, 2] + r^4 Subscript[a, 4]  *)
```

Like this, you can act also in other cases.

Let me advise you to avoid using subscripts, if it is not absolutely necessary. Using them may disturb some important operations depending on the ComplexityFunction, such as Simplify. To avoid it in the above example one can use the following construct:

```
expr /. x_*r^n_Integer /; n == 2 || n == 4 :> 
  ToExpression["a" <> ToString[n]]*r^n

(*  a2 r^2 + a4 r^4 + (A6 + B6) r^6  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: This has been very helpful. Thank you!